# how to draw vertical line in chart with XlsxWriter in python?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, charts, xlsxwriter

I have created a chart in Excel with python **XlsxWriter**. But I cannot add a vertical line on a point. Can somebody tell how to do this?

[image: This image contains a chart]

Following code creates the chart in excel.

```
line_chart1 = writer_object.book.add_chart({'type': 'line'})
line_chart1.add_series({'categories': [parameter,j+i,2,j+100+i,2],'name': 
         [parameter, 0, 4],'values': [parameter,j+i,4,j+100+i,4]})
line_chart1.add_series({'categories': [parameter,j+i,2,j+100+i,2],'name': 
         [parameter, 0, 5],'values': [parameter,j+i,5,j+100+i,5]})    
line_chart1.add_series({'name': [parameter, 0, 6],'categories': 
         [parameter,j+i,2,j+100+i,2],'values': [parameter,j+i,6,j+100+i,6], 
         'y2_axis':    True,})
area_chart1 = writer_object.book.add_chart({'type': 'area'})
area_chart1.add_series({'categories': 
         [parameter,j+i,2,j+100+i,2],'name': [parameter, 0, 3],'values': 
         [parameter,j+i,3,j+100+i,3],'fill':{'color': '#add8e6'}})
line_chart1.combine(area_chart1)        
line_chart1.set_size({'width': 700, 'height': 400})
line_chart1.set_title({ 'name': percen.index[i]})
line_chart1.set_x_axis({'name': 'Percentiles'})
line_chart1.set_y_axis({'name': 'Alerts'})
line_chart1.set_y2_axis({'name': 'WA_Ratio'})
```